# How do I iterate for all HDF5 files and save them as csv files

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, h5py

I am writing a python code that will loop over my SMAP HDF5 (10,000) files. I want to extract soil moisture rootzone and vegetation greenness. My code looks like this

```
import os
import tables
import h5py
import datetime as dt
import glob
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

direc = '/Users/24715447/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UTS/Soil_Moisture/SMAP/HDF' # the working directory (where your files are stored)
dirs = os.listdir(direc)

for idir in dirs: # this will iterate over the files in your working directory

    if idir.endswith('.h5'): # only for HDF5 files...
        hdf5 = tables.open_file(os.path.join(direc,idir))

        dataset = h5py.File(hdf5, 'r')

        longitude_values = np.array(list(dataset['cell_lon'])).flatten()
        latitude_values = np.array(list(dataset['cell_lat'])).flatten()
        soilMoisture_values = np.array(list(geo['sm_rootzone'])).flatten()
        Vegetation_greenness_values = np.array(list(geo['vegetation_greenness_fraction'])).flatten()
        dataset = pd.DataFrame({"lon": longitude_values, "lat": latitude_values, "soil_root": soilMoisture_values, "greenness": Vegetation_greenness_values})

        dataset.to_csv('/Users/24715447/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UTS/Soil_Moisture/SMAP/CSV_{idir}.csv')

        hdf5.close()
```

I get an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/24715447/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UTS/Soil_Moisture/SMAP/h5tocsv.py", line 14, in <module>
    dirs = os.listdir(direc)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/24715447/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UTS/Soil_Moisture/SMAP/HDF")'
(climate_process) UTS046280:SMAP 24715447$ python h5tocsv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/24715447/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UTS/Soil_Moisture/SMAP/h5tocsv.py", line 14, in <module>
    dirs = os.listdir(direc)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './HDF")'
(climate_process) UTS046280:SMAP 24715447$ python h5tocsv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/24715447/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UTS/Soil_Moisture/SMAP/h5tocsv.py", line 19, in <module>
    hdf5 = tables.openFile(os.path.join(direc,idir))
AttributeError: module 'tables' has no attribute 'openFile'
(climate_process) UTS046280:SMAP 24715447$ python h5tocsv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/24715447/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UTS/Soil_Moisture/SMAP/h5tocsv.py", line 19, in <module>
    hdf5 = tables.open_file(os.path.join(direc,idir))
  File "/Users/24715447/anaconda3/envs/climate_process/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tables/file.py", line 300, in open_file
    return File(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/24715447/anaconda3/envs/climate_process/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tables/file.py", line 750, in __init__
    self._g_new(filename, mode, **params)
  File "tables/hdf5extension.pyx", line 486, in tables.hdf5extension.File._g_new
tables.exceptions.HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5F.c", line 620, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
  File "H5VLcallback.c", line 3502, in H5VL_file_open
    failed to iterate over available VOL connector plugins
  File "H5PLpath.c", line 579, in H5PL__path_table_iterate
    can't iterate over plugins in plugin path '(null)'
  File "H5PLpath.c", line 620, in H5PL__path_table_iterate_process_path
    can't open directory: /Users/24715447/anaconda3/envs/climate_process/lib/hdf5/plugin
  File "H5VLcallback.c", line 3351, in H5VL__file_open
    open failed
  File "H5VLnative_file.c", line 97, in H5VL__native_file_open
    unable to open file
  File "H5Fint.c", line 1990, in H5F_open
    unable to read superblock
  File "H5Fsuper.c", line 617, in H5F__super_read
    truncated file: eof = 120927924, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 150224576

End of HDF5 error back trace
```

I expect to get csv files of the same filenames with only soil moisture and vegetation greenness. I want also to clip the values to these coordinates

box_lat = [-43.63, -10.66]
box_lon = [113.34, -153.57]

How do I revise my code? Please help me

Comment: It seems one of your HDF5 files got corrupted.  Do you have an alternate source for obtaining them?  Also, what do you mean you want to clip the values?  If a datapoint is outside that range, do you want to adjust the position to be in the range, or do you simply want to discard that datapoint?

Comment: I have a global dataset of soil moisture stored in the HDF file. I only want to clip Australia, the box_lat and box_lon are the Australian boundaries

Comment: You are reading from `geo['sm_rootzone']` and `geo['vegetation_greenness_fraction']`. Where is `geo` defined?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide a precise answer without more details about your folder/file structure and the HDF5 data schema. That said, I have identified several errors in your code and will show how to fix them.

First, as @Ribatan Ghosh noted, you are using the wrong method name to open the file with pytables (aka the tables package). That's why you get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tables' has no attribute 'openFile'
```

You then use the tables file object to open with h5py where a filename is expected. Your HDF5 dataset names use h5py syntax, so I'm 99.99% sure you want to use h5py to open. Also, the `with/as` context manager is the preferred way to open files.

Next, there is no need for all the Python gymnastics to create a np.array from a dataset. Just read the dataset.

Finally, it looks like you want to use a f-string to create the CSV filename, but forgot the initial `f`.

Code below is modified to reflect feedback above. It should work, but has not been tested.

```
for idir in dirs: # this will iterate over the files in your working directory
    if idir.endswith('.h5'): # only for HDF5 files...
        with h5py.File(os.path.join(direc,idir),'r') as hdf5:
            longitude_values = hdf5['cell_lon'][:] # to retrive data as np.array
            latitude_values = hdf5['cell_lat'][:]
            soilMoisture_values = hdf5['sm_rootzone'][:]
            Vegetation_greenness_values = hdf5['vegetation_greenness_fraction'][:]
            dataset = pd.DataFrame({"lon": longitude_values, "lat": latitude_values,
                      "soil_root": soilMoisture_values, "greenness": Vegetation_greenness_values)

            dataset.to_csv(f'/Users/24715447/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UTS/Soil_Moisture/SMAP/CSV_{idir}.csv')
```

As an aside, I prefer the `glob.iglob()` method to loop over file names. It is much simpler to use and doesn't require the `if` test. I didn't use it here because it adds a complication creating the CSV file name. If you use iglob, you can use `pathlib` stem to get the name. See the simple code snippet below:

```
from pathlib import Path;
for h5file in glob.iglob('direc/*.h5'): # this will iterate over h5 files in the directory
    print(Path(h5file).stem) # filename without h5 extension
```

Answer (score -1):

The error messages you are encountering indicate some issues with the file paths and the HDF5 file opening process.

1. File Path Issue:
   The error message FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory indicates that the directory you provided cannot be found. Make sure the directory path is correct and accessible. You might want to print the direc variable and check if it points to the right directory.
2. HDF5 File Opening Issue:
   The error message AttributeError: module 'tables' has no attribute 'openFile' is likely because the open_file method in the tables module is case-sensitive. The correct method name is open_file, not openFile. Update the line where you open the HDF5 file like this:

```
hdf5 = tables.open_file(os.path.join(direc, idir))
```

3. Clipping the Values:
   To clip the values to the specified coordinates, you can add a condition inside the loop that checks if the latitude and longitude fall within the specified bounds before saving the values to the CSV file. You can use numpy's logical indexing for this purpose. Modify the loop as follows:

```
box_lat = [-43.63, -10.66]
box_lon = [113.34, -153.57]

for idir in dirs:
    if idir.endswith('.h5'):
        hdf5 = tables.open_file(os.path.join(direc, idir))

        dataset = h5py.File(hdf5, 'r')

        longitude_values = np.array(list(dataset['cell_lon'])).flatten()
        latitude_values = np.array(list(dataset['cell_lat'])).flatten()
        soilMoisture_values = np.array(list(geo['sm_rootzone'])).flatten()
        Vegetation_greenness_values = np.array(list(geo['vegetation_greenness_fraction'])).flatten()

        # Filter the data to the specified coordinates
        mask = (box_lat[0] <= latitude_values) & (latitude_values <= box_lat[1]) & \
               (box_lon[0] <= longitude_values) & (longitude_values <= box_lon[1])

        # Create a DataFrame with the filtered data
        dataset = pd.DataFrame({
            "lon": longitude_values[mask],
            "lat": latitude_values[mask],
            "soil_root": soilMoisture_values[mask],
            "greenness": Vegetation_greenness_values[mask]
        })

        # Save to CSV file
        dataset.to_csv(f'/Users/24715447/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UTS/Soil_Moisture/SMAP/CSV_{idir}.csv')

        hdf5.close()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try your suggestion and update.